# How to set transparency and background color in Menu and taskbar in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

How to set background color and transparency of KDE main menu and taskbar widgets?

KDE Frameworks 5.44.0 / Plasma 5.12.6

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't have transparency for the panel, menu, and panel associated widgets with the default themes. You may need to look [elsewhere](https://www.opendesktop.org/search?projectSearchText=transparent) but make sure you back up your data first!

Comment: @DK Bose, changing transparency is the least important for me, mostly I want to set menu and panel color.

Comment: Then please post a screenshot of what your current "KDE main menu and taskbar widgets" look like and mention what you want to change. Alternatively, open **System Settings > Appearance > Colors** and choose from the schemes there.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but there's a similar question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a1lw2s/how_can_i_get_similar_transparency_of_the_taskbar/) with [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a1lw2s/how_can_i_get_similar_transparency_of_the_taskbar/eaqyze6) on how to modify your existing theme as well as suggestions to try other themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming breeze-light or breeze-dark theme is being used.

```
cp -r /usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/breeze-light/ ~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/
```

and then edit line *BackgroundNormal* from section *[Colors:Window]* of file *.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/breeze-light-custom/colors*

Set the color in RGB model.

Edit theme name in *.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/breeze-light-custom/colors* file.

*colors* file also has some more useful options for customizing desktop appearance.

Select newly created custom theme in system settings menu.